# Как скопировать последнее сообщение в VK через selenium на python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Я пытался скопировать последнее сообщение с помощью xpath, но я не могу отследить именно последнее.

Т.е. мне надо для работы этого кода, узнать какой xpath для последнего сообщения или по какому алгоритму он меняется.

Message = browser.find_element_by_xpath('xpath последнего сообщения').text

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: может лучше vk api использовать?

Comment: Большое спасибо, ваш совет очень пригодился.